# Doodles and Scribbles

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

[image: Doodles and Scribbles]
Sometimes I scribble on my notebook at work, but today it feels like the doodles are somehow connected...
What am I supposed to do with this?

Comment: You wouldn't happen to speak French, would you Auri?

Comment: I am indeed French, though that won't help you solve this puzzle!

Comment: oh well, at least I still know my days of the week! Guess I did retain a couple things from high school french lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shaded cells:

> The shaded cells are Braille for **POKER**.

Errors:

> Converting from hex to decimal, we get `31 11 42 14 54`. This is Tap Code for **LARDY**.

Calendar:

> Treating a day of rain as a dot, two days as a dash, and two days of sun as an inter-letter space, this is Morse code for **ASPIS**.

Tic-tac-toe:

> The locations of the Xs are the *corners* of the letters **NAMED**.

Gravestone:

> This is text written in the [Elder Futhark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elder_Futhark), spelling "Plato's fifth element" column-by-column; this is a cluephrase for **ETHER**.

Meta:

> Arranging the answers into a 5×5 grid, and reading down the diagonal and the left side...
>
>  `POKER`
>  `LARDY`
>  `ASPIS`
>  `NAMED`
>  `ETHER`
>
>  we get **PAPER PLANE**, a good suggestion for what you might do with this page of doodles.

Comment: And I might just do that! Well done Deusovi !